# PathBased routing AWS EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

Is path based routing allowed on AWS EKS load balancer controller.

I have been trying to setup a path based routing based on Ingress rules but I am receiving an error when I access the URL's. Here is my ingress code.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingresscon
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/tags: Env=Dev,Billing=DevTeam
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/security-groups: sg-03dbe1faa37794bd2
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP":80},{"HTTP": 19000}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-port: '80'

spec:
  rules:
    - host: example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /game
            backend:
              serviceName: test2048
              servicePort: 8080
          - path: /web
            backend:
              serviceName: nginx
              servicePort: 80
          - path: /*
            backend:
              serviceName: nginx
              servicePort: 80
```

Accessing my url http://example.com displays nginx web page. However, if I access http://example.com/game or http://example.com/web displays an error.
Am i missing anything in setting up Ingress rules?

Comment: Im not sure my idea : manually add relevent path in Target group(listener) of Application LoadBalancer and try accessing. If works, automate it.

Comment: can you explain what do you mean by manually. Based on the ingress definitions I see that listner running on port 80 does have the rules which states /web to TG1 and /game to TG2

Comment: what is the error and can you post your nginx deployment/service spec in your question?

Comment: This config looks correct to me. If you look at the routing in the AWS UI, does there appear to be an issue with the ordering of the paths?

Comment: @gohnm'c and @ jordanm, Thanks for picking up this question. I just see an error 404-nginx error. And coming to the ordering of paths, I changed the orders but the issue is the same

Comment: I am also facing same issue, getting 404 error, Can you please share if you got any solution for the issue.